# Select distinct values from a numeric column with comma separator

Tags: postgresql

I have Values like this in postgresql table

```
account_id
integer
----------
749
749
749
749
532
```

I want to select them as (749, 532)

```
----------
Detail of Question
```

In a WHERE clause I want to show some id's like this

**WHERE account_id in (749,532)**

from a column that have repeated values;

account_id(Column)

749
749
749
749
532
532

or may be some other values. And I only want to select each value once and with comma separated in above mentioned WHERE Clause

I wrote following query but it doesn't give required results

WHERE account_id in (SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT(vc.account_id) ORDER BY vc.account_id)               FROM adempiere.c_validcombination vc                                                              LEFT JOIN adempiere.c_bp_vendor_acct bva ON vc.c_validcombination_id = bva.v_liability_acct
WHERE bva.ad_client_id = 11 )

It returns values like this {749, 532} but I need them as (749, 532)

Thank you

Comment: What result does the code you wrote give you?

Comment: `select distinct(account_id) from table`

Comment: Thank you for reply. But "select distinct(account_id) from table" simply doesn't fulfill my requirement. it shows result distint values in separate cells. I need all value in one cell with comma separator like (749, 532)

Comment: Don't use an array and you're done. The ORDER BY also looks obsolete, just like DISTINCT. Keep it simple: SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE x IN(SELECT y FROM t2);

Answer (score 1):

Check [string_agg()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html):

```
SELECT
  string_agg(DISTINCT account_id::text, ', ') AS result
FROM 
  table_name;
```

Comment: Dear Frank please see my actual query and requirement: WHERE account_id in ((SELECT DISTINCT(vc.account_id) FROM adempiere.c_validcombination vc LEFT JOIN adempiere.c_bp_vendor_acct bva ON vc.c_validcombination_id = bva.v_liability_acct WHERE bva.ad_client_id = 11 GROUP BY vc.account_id)) Result should be as follow WHERE account_id in (749, 532)

Comment: @see2rizwan: I really don't understand your comment, please edit your question and put the entire query over there. WHERE account_id in (749, 532)  is the same as WHERE account_id in (749, 749, 749, 749, 532)

Comment: I have updated my question. Would you please comment on that?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT account_id FROM table GROUP BY account_id
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. It doesn't provide me required solution. i am mentioning actual query with required result here. please comment on it.                                              WHERE account_id in ((SELECT DISTINCT(vc.account_id) FROM adempiere.c_validcombination vc
   LEFT JOIN adempiere.c_bp_vendor_acct bva ON vc.c_validcombination_id = bva.v_liability_acct
   WHERE bva.ad_client_id = 11 GROUP BY vc.account_id))

Result Needed is as follow

WHERE account_id in (749, 532)